# C++, code to make console program contents fit to screen(display the same size) on all different windows computers, Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dynamic, console-application, zooming

I'm new to stackoverflow, however, I always find good tips and tricks here and I thought I would join.

I'm currently in my second year of college and I decided to start working on my first portfolio project. My project is going to be a text-based turn-based RPG game that runs on the console for now, with the intention of learning DX11 and import it there and create a GUI. However, I'm currently focused on creating it as a console application first.

Currently, I'm having an issue making my application increase in either font-size (dynamically so that it displays the same on every windows computer) or just simply have the output scale up for its contents to fit the screen (on every windows computer). I have tried many methods concerning font-size change, the one that worked for me and worked on other PCs is the following:

```
#include <windows.h>


CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi{};
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;                   // Width of each character in the font
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 38;                  // Height
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas"); // Choose your font
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
```

While this method does work on my pc and all other computers, it doesn't do the job as well as I would have hoped. Since this code simply just enlarges text, on different monitors it can either be too large or too small. Whereas I am searching for a method that would simply fit the content on my console program output to screen, so that it displays the same on every computer.

While I know how to enlarge the font on the console (zoom in), I am looking for a method that displays the program the way I want it to on launch.

I am kindly asking if anyone has any tips in this matter, keep in mind this isn't homework assignment, or any graded project, this is simply for my portfolio project which is already teaching me a lot.

Glad to be a member of this community, thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try to get the display/monitor properties first, so you can scale the font size proportionally to the width and height of the display.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, any ideas how I go about getting the display/monitor resolution?

Comment: There are a lot of (graphical) libraries featuring Dsiplay property functions. For example: SDL2, SFML, GLFW etc. I personally have used SDL2 and it works very well. They are all cross-platform and should work on most OS. I could show a sample in SDL2 or GLFW.

Comment: I would really appreciate seeing an example in whichever you think is more appropriate to what I'm asking for! Thank you once again for your help

Comment: Np. I would then need to know how many characters you wanna allow on one line to be visible and how big the console is gonna be. Should it stretch to the whole screen? Should the console output also resize when you resize the console itself?

Comment: The width of the console is currently 142 characters and as for the height I would say around 44 characters, The console output should remain the same but the user has the ability to zoom in and zoom out, I just want it 142 char width and 44 char height on launch!
Edit: I already have the full screen on launch functionality, and I also have disabled scrolling up or down in the console.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I posted a solution below. There is one issue you need to consider: When you move the console to another display/monitor with different resolution, you need to resize everything again. So you might gonna need to check in your game loop, if the display has changed and resize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale your font size to your whole display, you would need to retrieve your display properties, so you can change the font width and height relative to the display width and height.

Since you are using the Windows API, I used functions included in `Windows.h`. You can only choose one of your displays at a time tho.

You specify the display with `SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(displayIndex, displayMode)`.

You might need to `#include <cmath>` to use `std::round()` depending on environment.

```
int charactersPerRow = 142;
int charactersPerCol = 44;

HWND activeWindow = GetActiveWindow();
HMONITOR activeMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(activeWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);  // Get Monitor closest to console
MONITORINFO monitorInfo{};
monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
GetMonitorInfo(activeMonitor, &monitorInfo);                        // Receive monitor info and store it in monitorInfo

int displayWidth = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left;
int displayHeight = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top;

CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi{};
cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = static_cast<short>(std::round((float)displayWidth / charactersPerRow));        // Width of each character in the font rounded
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = static_cast<short>(std::round((float)displayHeight / charactersPerCol));       // Height rounded
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas");                             // Choose your font
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
```

You might wanna check, if your active monitor has changed in your game loop and resize everything again. So i would recommend putting all the code for retrieving width and height and resizing the font in its own function and call it in your loop whenever your active monitor (where your console is located in) changes.

**DO NOTE** that you can zoom in the font with **CTRL+Mouse wheel**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, while waiting for your reply I did some tests and I managed to make it work on most other screens however not every other resolution. After trying your code, it did work on my computer, however, for my friend that uses an ultra wide monitor with 3440x1440 resolution it turned out like this [link](https://i.imgur.com/loCQuqi.png) whereas it should be like this on every screen : [link](https://i.imgur.com/yexa65n.png) , one thing to note too. On this friend's computer, the font ONLY changes when my app is run with admin privileges. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Almnayer Again, sorry for my late response. In case you still haven't fixed it, do you mean the problem with the line going in two rows or that the font gets stretched on his monitor? The stretching part makes sense since he uses an ultra wide screen, so to fit the same amount of characters it stretches the letters and makes it look way too stretched.

Comment: no problem!
I still haven't fixed the issue because I have spent more than two days attempting to find a solution and I decided to move on and get back to it later. The problem is with the output compressing still on different screen sizes and screen resolutions.
In this case, the line going in two rows. I don't mind it being stretched, I just want it to display like how I want it to, without any output prints malfunctioning on every computer.